# How do I get the dot product of two matrices using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

I am trying to get the dot-product of a vector and a matrix using `numpy` but I get following exception:`ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)`

Essentially I just want to multiply a 2x1-matrix (a 2-row-vector) with a 2x2-matrix, but `numpy` doesn't seem to support this. I already tried doing the same thing with a 1x2-matrix, and that worked, but didn't give me the result i was looking for.

The code I am using is:

```
inputs = np.matrix([[1], [0]])
weights = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
print(np.add(np.dot(inputs, weights), 0))

#desired result = array([1, 3])
```

So my question would be: How can I perform my desired operation with numpy?

**EDIT**

This is what happens:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.matrix([[1], [0]])
>>> b = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> a * b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 309, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: shapes (2,1) and (2,2) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dot product is for vectors of the same size. You can just multiply matrices in numpy. If you need a different solution - please include your code in the question and the desired outcome.

```
a = np.array([2,3])
b = np.array([[4,5],[6,7]])

>>> a * b
array([[ 8, 15],
    [12, 21]])
```

Update per updated question:

```
inputs = np.matrix([[1], [0]])
weights = np.matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> weights * inputs
matrix([[1],
        [3]])
```

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: It was nothing more than the order of operands... I switched them and it worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: As an aside, let's all take a moment to appreciate that brilliant username